# Custom functions not working in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, function, vba

For some reason custom functions don't seem to be running in Excel.  I created the simple function below but it always returns zero as a value whether it is used as a worksheet function or called from a procedure.  Anyone know what I am doing wrong or if there is a setting somewhere I am missing?

```
  Public Function Testthisout(number As Double) As Double
    result = number * number
  End Function

  Public Sub TESTFUNCTION()
    Dim number As Double
    Dim result As Double

    Application.Volatile (True)

    number = 4
    result = Testthisout(number)
    MsgBox result
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change you function to:

```
Public Function Testthisout(number As Double) As Double
  result = number * number
  Testthisout = result
End Function
```

Comment: nope, still get 0 returned.  Dunno if I have to reinstall excel maybe

Comment: Try `Testthisout = number * number`. Your problem is that you don't assign `result` to the function's returning value.

Comment: Many thanks- obvious in hindsight, but highly frustating when you miss it!